# ExtJS 4 - Changing legend colour dynamically in LineChart

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts

I've been researching without any luck about how to change the x legend color in a Line chart. Do you know how can I do it ? 
Attached image of the chart.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the label property on the axis config, like so:

```
axes: [{
    type: 'numeric',
    position: 'left',
    fields: ['data1'],
    title: {
       text: 'Sample Values',
       fontSize: 15
    },
       grid: true,
       minimum: 0
    }, {
       type: 'category',
       position: 'bottom',
       fields: ['name'],
       title: {
          text: 'Sample Values',
          fontSize: 15
       },
       label: {
          fill: '#FF0000'
       }
}],
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/hki) so that you can see this working. Note that the config item with ExtJs 4 is `fill`, NOT color as you would expect.